Mathematica Online Problem: Print to PDF/ Programatic Exporting as PDF
Problem Succinctly:
Can't Print-to-PDF or Export a programmatically generated notebook with ToBoxes containing cells.
I have a project where:

I want to run a notebook in Mathematica online
Get it to programmatically open a second notebook
Populate the second notebook with a combination of text/graphics/grids/ and evaluated equations.
Allow this 2nd notebook to be printed as a pdf (preferably via programmatically exporting as a pdf).

I have made some significant progress. Although 'online' version is trickier than desktop.
I have rasterized my grids, and used NotebookWrite [nb, ToBoxes[Image]] to archive this.
The new notebook renders adequately in the new window.
However, when I click File -> Print to PDF -> I get a "Failed to Load PDF" error message within my browser. Saving the URL reveals a Zero KB file (so it is not my browser's viewer).
For example, this code renders but does not permit Print-to-pdf / export / publish:
nb0 = EvaluationNotebook[];
nb = CreateDocument[];

d=Rasterize[
Grid[
  {{"Report Prepared by:", AuthorName}, {"Date:", Now}}, 
  Alignment -> {Left, Right, {Bottom, Top}}
  ]
 ];
 NotebookWrite[nb,ToBoxes[d]]

However, this code permits print-to-pdf
nb0 = EvaluationNotebook[];
    nb = CreateDocument[];
NotebookWrite[nb,Cell["Text Example"]]

Interestingly I get no response from the desktop effective:
Export[example.pdf, nb]. I'd be keen to hear any ideas about triggering a SystemDialogue save for the new notebook.
I'm new to this forum. I'm also not a mathematician or programmer.
(I'm a clinician). (I'm almost frying my kernal trying to understand front-end from kernal).
Thanks.
